# Tracking destination pages in Google Analytics after auto-complete search

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, google-analytics, analytics

The primary interface to a site we're building is a jQuery UI auto-complete search box. Users enter some keywords, select the result and are redirected using `location.href` to their selected page.

All the searches are being tracked properly (`_gaq.push(['_trackPageview','/?s=' + current_term']`) before the redirect but the destination page is never logged. All the destination pages are set to `/` in GA.

I've looked but can't find a way to explicitly set the destination before the redirect. Do you have any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The destination pages have GA tracking on them, yes?  And, they are on your site, right?  Redirects aren't logged... landing on pages are.

Comment: Yes, the redirect destinations are on the same site, with the same Analytics code. The redirect page view appears to be tracked, just not associated with the search.

Answer (score 3):

It could be due to the fact that

```
_gaq.push(...)
```

is asynchronous. And then you're calling a redirect with `window.location` stopping code execution.

A solution could be to attach a callback function when calling `_gaq.push`:

```
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview','/?s=' + current_term], function() {
    // redirect user here...
    // window.location = ...
})
```

Comment: That looks promising. Is the callback guaranteed to be completed (ie the tracking is recorded) before the redirect?  And, even more ideally, is there a timeout limit that can be set?

Comment: Sure, a callback – as the name suggest – is returned after the async function is completed. You don't need any timeout at all.

Comment: I don't know if it's a typo but '/?s=' + current_term'] should be '/?s=' + current_term] <-- (no last single quote)

Answer (score 1):

Do you have internal search configured in GA?

It's possible that your searches are being logged but the parameter being stripped out from the url on the top pages report.

In that case you should be able to see the data on the internal search keyword reports.

If that's the case and If you still want the parameter to show up in the top page report than you need to uncheck the checkbox on the profile configuration that defines if the search parameter is stripped out from the url.